# getting error in android WebView net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a WordPress Woo-commerce website which includes the UPI transactions, website working perfectly in desktop and mobile browsers. I convert the above-mentioned website as an APK through an Android web view, but unfortunately in app does not perform a UPI transaction section. I got an error message.

> Web page not available The web page at
> `upi://pay?pa=xxxxxxx@okaxis&pn=Malayaliescart&am=25.00&cu=INR&tn=OrderID 3826` could not be loaded because: `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

But the UPI working on a mobile browser. when I click on the UPI section, the browser asks me which UPI application shall open?

Below is the code.

```
    String websiteURL = "https://www.xxxx.com/"; // sets web url
    private WebView webview;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if( ! CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(this)) //returns true if internet available
        {
            //if there is no internet do this
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //Toast.makeText(this,"No Internet Connection, Chris",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("No internet connection available")
                    .setMessage("Please Check you're Mobile data or Wifi network.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    //.setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

        }
        else
        {
            //Webview stuff
            webview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
            webview.loadUrl(websiteURL);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());

        }

        //Swipe to refresh functionality
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        webview.reload();
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        //Keep webview in app when clicking links
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

    //set back button functionality
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() { //if user presses the back button do this
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) { //check if in webview and the user can go back
            webview.goBack(); //go back in webview
        } else { //do this if the webview cannot go back any further

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this) //alert the person knowing they are about to close
                    .setTitle("EXIT")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure. You want to close this app?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
        }
    }
    }



class CheckNetwork {

    private static final String TAG = CheckNetwork.class.getSimpleName();

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context)
    {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) ((ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (info == null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"no internet connection");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(info.isConnected())
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection available...");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG," internet connection");
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` what `url` is given to load, if it starts with `upi` scheme then use `startActivity` with `ACTION_VIEW` and this whole uri set as data payload. also return false in this case and don't call `loadUrl`, just `return true` then (as given URL is handled, but not by `WebView`)

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("upi") {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent upiIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        view.getContext().startActivity(upiIntent);
    }
    else view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending) you have some samples how to open 3rd-party apps with given URI, ale be aware of and handle [`ActivityNotFoundException`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#complete-example) (when there is no app for such URI, in this case UPI payment)